# ADO.NET Data Services 'Astoria' and Caching

Tags: ado.net, caching, wcf-data-services

I just started diving into ADO.NET Data Services for a project, and I quickly ran into a problem. At first I was amazed by the performance, but then I realized that the data was cached. My project relies on real-time data, and I'd love to use the ADO.NET Data Services REST query syntax (without needing to use WCF or SOAP), but without caching.

I saw on the ADO.NET Data Services introduction page ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc907912.aspx)) that they do not yet have API support for managing the cache duration or anything of the like.

Anyone have any ideas of how to accomplish this, or turn off the cache?

Comment: Hrmmm,

I'll be waiting for an answer on this one cause I wasn't aware the the actual data was cached. Are you absolutely sure it's the data that is being cached and not the queries that are LINQ processed for each REST based URI that you use to access your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the data context has MergeOption set to AppendOnly. This means that re-requests will only add new entities and will not update existing ones. Try setting MergeOption to OverwriteChanges:

```
this.context.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
```

This worked for me when I noticed this! If you're using real time data then you might want to turn off change tracking completely with the NoTracking option.

Answer (score 2):

We made a post recently about how to use ETags to control the caching policy of data returned from a Data Service , http://blogs.msdn.com/astoriateam/archive/2008/04/22/optimistic-concurrency-data-services.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That link is helpful, but it doesn't really talk about ETags and caching, it just mentions that ETags can be *used* for caching. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

In depth details on the [ETag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541486(PROT.10).aspx)